# How can I pass arguments to a program at runtime?

Tags: python-3.x

For example, I have a cyclical script that makes a request to the Api every 10 minutes. I want to change the parameters of the next request without stopping it.

Cmd is blocked at run time.

Reading arguments from a environment file or a database doesn't seem safe to me. I think it's possible that while variables are being changed, the script may access them when they are not yet ready and cause errors.

Any thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: If you are reading a single value from the database you will always get a consistent value. If you are reading multiple values and your database supports transactions (and the writing code is using them), then you will *also* always receive a consistent value. Alternately, you could implement a simple socket interface (or even an http server) to receive updates while the program is running. There are lots of options; you should probably try something first and then come here with specific technical questions if it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: This is probably a question for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/  however....  as you have no doubt started to consider, your problem requires the input to come from an alternate source OR you need to allow your script to periodically check "does the user want to provide input?".

Comment: Thank you your ideas helped, after trying several, I settled on the option of parsing a config file, using the FileLock package, blocking access to the file from more than one process.